# Javascript Redirect Timeout

Tags: javascript, command-line, opera

I am trying to start opera from command line and redirect it to a page in 30 seconds. What I'm trying now is:

```
C:\Programme\Opera\opera.exe -newpage javascript:function%20func1(){window.location.href='http://localhost/';}setTimeout('func1()',30000);
```

Which is returing a page with as content "1". Func1 is never called. Is there a good way to solve this inline? Or should I create a page with this content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a better solution:

1.) change the command line to:

```
C:\Programme\Opera\opera.exe -newpage file://localhost/C:/redirect.html
```

2.) create the file redirect.html with the code for a redirect:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Startup</title>
    <script>
    function redirect()
    {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost/startup.php';
    }
    setTimeout('redirect()',60000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Loading...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(redirect,60000);`
is regarded as a better syntax since it does not involve a hidden eval

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the original example, you should have put void() around the setTimeout() call. setTimeout() returns a timeout identifier (in this case the number 1) which becomes the output of the javascript: URL. Whatever a javascript: URL 'returns' is used as the source for a document.